# R Shiny reactive and new.env() - select group of stock symbols to get data and plot multiple dygraphs

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod, shiny-reactivity, r-dygraphs

I am trying to render multiple `dygraphs` using `eapply`. The data of the corresponding symbols comes via `quantmod::getsymbols`. The symbols (or varying groups of symbols) should be selectable via `selectInput`.

Unfortunately, I can't get the graph to update after selecting the `selectInput`. Does anyone here have an idea how this should be handled?

I would be grateful for any advice!

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(quantmod)


# just for illustration purpose, the symbols may vary and the number of select values may vary. The point is, that the input to the getsymbols function are multiple tickers, that can change

sym_bols1 <- c("TSLA", "EEM", "UBS")
sym_bols2 <- c("AAPL", "MSFT")


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidPage(    
    titlePanel("Multiple Tickers"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(selectInput("symbl", "Symbolliste", c("sym_bols1", "sym_bols2"))),

      mainPanel(uiOutput("ui"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data_env <- new.env(
    observe({
      quantmod::getSymbols(get(input$symbl),  from="2023-01-01", env=data_env)
    })
  )
  

  observe({
    
    dy_graph <- eapply(data_env, function(x_ts) {
      dygraphs::renderDygraph(dygraph(x_ts[, 1:4], group="multi",
                                      width=600, height=400))
    })
    
    output$ui <- renderUI(dy_graph)
  }, env=data_env)
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can't put an observer in `new.env`, an observer does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way:

```r
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(quantmod)


# just for illustration purpose, the symbols may vary and the number of select values may vary. The point is, that the input to the getsymbols function are multiple tickers, that can change

sym_bols1 <- c("TSLA", "EEM", "UBS")
sym_bols2 <- c("AAPL", "MSFT")


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidPage(    
    titlePanel("Multiple Tickers"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(selectInput("symbl", "Symbolliste", c("sym_bols1", "sym_bols2"))),
      
      mainPanel(uiOutput("ui"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # reactive environment
  DataEnv <- reactive({
    data_env <- new.env()
    quantmod::getSymbols(get(input$symbl), from = "2023-01-01", env = data_env)
    data_env
  })
  
  Dygraphs <- reactive({
    eapply(DataEnv(), function(x_ts) {
      renderDygraph(dygraph(x_ts[, 1:4], group = "multi",
                            width = 600, height = 400))
    })
  })
  
  output$ui <- renderUI(do.call(tagList, Dygraphs()))

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But the graphs are close to each other. You can separate them by using

```r
  Dygraphs <- reactive({
    eapply(DataEnv(), function(x_ts) {
      tags$div(
        style = "margin-bottom: 60px;",
        renderDygraph({
          dygraph(
            x_ts[, 1:4], group = "multi", width = 600, height = 400
          )
        })
      )
    })
  })
```

Comment: perfect solution to what i was looking for! I was struggling with the reactive environment.